# Put div's in each corner of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble putting 4 different div's in each corner of the page, I don't know if you'll need my html/css code, but if you do just comment and I'll put it up.

If you know how just put it on jsfiddle, that would be great.

Comment: I think it's quicker if you put whatever you have on a http://jsfiddle.net for us to fix.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/V6ysC/

Answer (score 3):

Using markup like this:

```
<div class="box top left"></div>
<div class="box top right"></div>
<div class="box bottom left"></div>
<div class="box bottom right"></div>
```

You could use the following CSS:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.box.top { top: 0; }
.box.right { right: 0; }
.box.left: { left: 0; }
.box.bottom { bottom: 0 }
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/PvUNT/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something other than just this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:20; right:20;">bottom right</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:20; right:20;">top right</div>
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:20; left:20;">bottom left</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:20; left:20;">top left</div>
</body></html>
```

?